# How to check if a 10x10 field has ended in a 2d board game

Tags: scala, field, 2d-games

The current grid, a 10x10 field, initially all cells are false (i.e. no walls).

```
private var field: Array[Array[Boolean]] = Array.ofDim[Boolean](10, 10)
```

That is the code for the field, and I wanna know how to write the code if I want to check that the player on the board has reached at the end of the board/field. 
Example - player position is (9,5) 9 is the end of the field and one move to the right would be out of the field. So how do I check that if the player is told to move 1 place to the right it does nothing as the field has ended?

Comment: Can you show us what you have got so far, and where the problem is? It seems that you want more than just `if (newX < 0 || newX > 9 || newY < 0 || newY > 9) ...`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check if the next position is in the board or not. As you have mentioned, valid positions for x and y are 0 - 9.

```
def canMove(x : Int, y : Int) : Boolean = {
      x >= 0 && x < 10 && y >= 0 && y < 10
}
```

This function returns true if `x >= 0 && x < 10 && y >= 0 && y < 10` is true and false otherwise. As parameters, you need to pass the next position, for example call `canMove(players_pos_x + 1, players_pos_y)` if you want to check if it's possible to move right.

Just one tip: Consider having the size of the grid set as a constant - in case you needed to change the size of the board later, you can change just the constant. You will not have to go through whole code and look for every usage of the size of the board. If you follow this recommendation, replace "10" in the function with "board_size" constant.

Comment: thank you for the help, I did try what you mentioned above but it doesn't seem to work.

 if(field(playerX - 1)(playerY) == false && ....) {
      playerX = playerX - 1
      checkBounty();
    }

I kind of need something after the && operator to check if the field ends or not
I have tried simple commands like x >= 0 && x < 10 && y >= 0 && y < 10 either of these but none seem to work

Comment: I have put it like this but still doesn't work

if(field(playerX - 1)(playerY) == false && canMove(playerX - 1 ,playerY) == true) {
      playerX = playerX - 1
      checkBounty();
    }
  }

Comment: try to switch the conditions: ` if(canMove(playerX - 1 ,playerY) == true && field(playerX - 1)(playerY) == false) { playerX = playerX - 1 checkBounty(); } }`

Comment: as you wrote it, you first accessed the out-of-bounds index (guess it raised an exception) and after that you tried to check if the index is valid, which is too late

Comment: I tried that still doesnt work

 if(field(playerX - 1)(playerY) == false && playerX - 1 > 0 ) { playerX = playerX - 1 checkBounty(); } } 

I tried something like that but still doesn't work, I asked my lecturer and he said the code above is almost correct just that theres something with the size of field and he said if you consider playerX - 1 > 0, is >0 correct?